# PHP função da classe!

Tags: php

Criei uma função dentro da classe que recebe um parâmetro e troca o valor de uma variável da classe, mas ela não funciona. Alguém pode explicar-me o porquê? O resultado dá `NULL`

```
<?php

class book{

    public $nome;

    function nao($x){
        $nome = $x;
    }
}

$pirata = new book();

$pirata->nao("caribe");

echo $pirata->nome;
var_dump($pirata);
```

Comment: Você não está definindo o valor do campo `$nome`. O método `nao` está apenas criando uma variável local (que não pode ser acessada fora dela). Para alterar um campo global, utilize o [`$this`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.basic.php), por exemplo: `$this->nome = $x`

Comment: @ValdeirPsr Seria interessante se você colocasse como resposta e se possível exemplificasse, pra que a pergunta possa ser marcada como respondida.

Comment: yaaay gratiluz!!! funcionou perfeitamente =DDD

Answer (score 1):

> O correto seria um Get e Set, e não se esqueça do "$this" para referenciar um valor global

```
<?php

class book{

    public $nome;

    function setNome($x){
        $this->nome = $x;
    }

    function getNome(){
        return $this->nome;
    }
}

$pirata = new book();
$pirata->setNome("caribe");

echo $pirata->getNome();
```